# How can I create and return CSV, not XML, in an ASMX Web Service, using SOAP with Attachments?

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, csv, asmx

Let's say I have a class like this:

```
class Person
{
    public string name;
    public string address;
    public string city;
    public string state;
    public string zip;
}
```

And I'm performing a data dip on a database:

```
Select Name, Address, City, State, Zip
FROM Persons_Tbl
```

I am storing the data in in the Person class, via SqlDataReader.

Normally, the Web Service will return the data and it'll be XML formatted.  However, I want to return it as CSV, not XML.  I realize that web services return either XML or JSON.  But there is something called SOAP with Attachments.  Can the attachment be CSV and, if so, how could I do this?

Answer (score 2):

[SOAP with Attachments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP_with_Attachments) (SwA) was never standardized:

> SwA is a W3C Note. It was submitted as a proposal, but it was not adopted by the W3C. Instead, MTOM is the W3C Recommendation for handling binary data in SOAP messages.

In any case, the legacy ASMX web service technology supported neither SwA nor MTOM. Is there some reason you can't use WCF? It does support MTOM.

Comment: No, not at all.  I don't know much about WCF, to be quite honest.  If I can leverage WCF + MTOM to send a CSV file, I'd certainly do it.  Can you recommend any tutorials or links for WCF + MTOM for CSV?  Is WCF the same as Web Services but with more features, or is WCF not a type of web service?   Thank you very much.

Comment: WCF replaced the old ASMX technology over five years ago. ASMX was a version 1.0 attempt at web services by Microsoft. I suggest you look at [tag:WCF] as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the Web Service call to send a file, or you only care about the output being a CSV?

If you only need a CSV formatted output, you can send the CSV as a string and then save it to a file in the application that consumes the web service:

```
string csvFile = webService.GetCSV()
File.WriteAllText(filePath, csvFile );
```

Do note that it will still return XML, but your data (string) would be in CSV format. You will have to create some helper methods to take your object and convert it into CSV format.

There are a few other implementations that are based on how you plan on using that web service.

Comment: Thank you for your response!  I'm looking for a web service in C# that sends a CSV file, which is why I suggested SOAP With Attachments.  Unfortunately, I don't have access to the response which consumes the web service -- it's in Java and created by another party.  I'm only sending out the web service and this party takes that response and consumes it.  Which is why I was asking if I can send a CSV file, somehow, with a Web Service.  Why CSV?  Because the other party wants it in CSV.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: This may help then: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms824597.aspx. Otherwise you can send the CSV file using Stream: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530045/how-to-transfer-file-through-web-service

Comment: Note that your second link is an example of a WCF service and doesn't use stream.